# Why the view not redraw with m.request in Mithril?

Tags: javascript, ajax, view, mithril.js

I have this example:

```
controller : function() {
    var responseFolder = m.prop("");
    var pathDirectory = m.prop("C://");` 

    function clickChangeFolder(folder) {
        pathDirectory(pathDirectory() + folder + "/");
        responseFolder(m.request({
            method : "GET",
            url : "my url",
            data : {root:pathDirectory()}
        }));
    }  
    return {
        responseFolder: m.request({
            method : "GET",  
            url : "http://localhost:8080/Mithril_directory/GetFolders",
            data : {root:pathDirectory()}
        }),
    }

view : function(ctrl) {
    return [
        m("ul" , ctrl.responseFolder().map(function(folder) {
            return [
                m("li.liFolder" , {
                    onclick : ctrl.clickChangeFolder.bind(null, folder.name)
                }, 
                folder.name), 
           ];
      })
 ]}
```

The first time the request is ok but when I click in the folder the second request is ok but the view not redraw, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the mithril documentation](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.request.html#basic-usage),

> The basic usage pattern for `m.request` returns an `m.prop` getter-setter,
>   which is populated when the AJAX request completes.

So what happens with your code is that on the controller's return object, `ctrl.responseFolder` is an `m.prop` that has nothing to do with the `responseFolder` variable declared before.

In order to get the view redrawn after each click, you need to assign the initial request to `responseFolder`, so it will become a getter-setter, and then return it to the view, which will be re-rendered on each new request.

```
var responseFolder = m.request({...});
...
return {
    responseFolder: responseFolder,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98726/discussion-between-irrech-and-vier).